# How to resize the menu Icons in main window toolbar

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.6

I want to find a way to change the size of icons in the menus (like New,Open,etc.) main window toolbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKSjV.png

i want this images of the icons become greater than this size

Answer (score 0):

Adjust [QToolBar::setMinimumHeight()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#minimumHeight-prop) or [QToolBar::setMinimumSize()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) to your needs.

And don't forget to use appropriate icon sizes then.